# Flash In Mobile Websites

Tags: flash

I've been told that in order to have a website "mobile friendly" you need to ensure that flash is not being used on the website.  I'm not sure why this is the case, can someone explain?

Comment: 1.) iOS devices never supported flash (there goes a huge junk of your mobile audience), 2.) Adobe stopped supporting Flash on Android devices (there goes pretty much the rest of your mobile audience, eventually), even 'though many devices still have the flash player installed 3.) Flash was never really the greatest platform for mobile.

Comment: You can check this out [Website Design - When You Should and
Shouldn't Use Flash](http://www.businessknowhow.com/internet/flash.htm). hope to help

Answer (score 0):

Flash is a 3rd party plugin that is not compatible with most mobile environments such as iOS and newer Android devices (as of version 4.1). HTML5 is emerging as the technology alternative to flash.

Steve Job's [Thoughts on Flash](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/) is some good reading regarding Apple's choice not to support it on their mobile devices.

Comment: I have Galaxy S III with Android Jelly Bean and I have Flash Player. :) Why do you think it's not supported?

Comment: @JordanJambazov I have a galaxy nexus with JB and a flash player as well.  It is not however supported http://www.mobileburn.com/20312/news/adobe-no-longer-accepting-new-installs-for-flash-player-on-android

Comment: You can't install Flash via the Play Store on devices with Android 4.1. Your device either came with Flash installed or you installed it before that switch. But once you're on a Flash-less 4.1 device, there's no supported way to add Flash support back in.

Comment: Hmmm...  So what are people doing with all those flash files they have out there.  Are there flash to HTML5 converters?  Do they work well?

Comment: @AnnSanderson there are flash to html5 converters, I cannot speak to their efficacy since I have never used one.

Comment: As far I know, there are some browser implementations for iOS and Android, that allow Flash playback, like Puffin. It's not a 3rd party plugin though, but relies on a remote cloud service (correct me if I'm wrong). However, it's obvious that Flash is not a mobile friendly technology.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly because iOS doesn't support Flash natively.

You can use Flash to develop apps for iOS devices and publish them using the packager for iPhone in Flash CS5. Apple announced during 2010 that they wouldn't allow applications built using 3rd party development tools (such as Unity and Flash) to be distributed through the App Store, but they've since lifted those restrictions.

But the web browser in iOS devices still won't play Flash content.

Why Apple is holding back on Flash content is a matter with strong opinions, but in the end the answer is quite simple: Because Apple believe they will make more money in the long run by banning Flash content.

Comment: Since Android (4.1) has joined iOS in the no-flash crowd, I think the strong opinions simply don't matter too much anymore: Flash (on mobile) is gone. Now the strong opinions can be about: when will it leave for the non-mobile sites?

Comment: How do CS5 developed iOS apps help with one's website?